# failed to display data in $firebaseArray

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I tried to display my firebase data on html through $firebaseArray. Why is there nothing to display?

My data is like(viewed on the firebase dash),

[image]

My code is roughly like such(not complete, but I think it is enough to demo the problem),
http://jsfiddle.net/bp6cp0sh/3/

html:

```
<body ng-app = "testApp">
    <div ng-controller="angularfirecontroller">
        <ul>
            <li np-repeat="message in messages">
                {{message.user}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", ["firebase"]);
testApp.controller("angularfirecontroller", function($scope, $firebaseArray){

    var dataRef = new Firebase("https://boiling-inferno-1234.firebaseio.com/messages");

    $scope.messages = $firebaseArray(dataRef);

});
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work and your angular module needs to be defined with an array of dependencies, such as `["firebase"]`.

Comment: I fixed the fiddle now. It now shows what I want to show. Dependencies grammar is fixed too, but it does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` has a typo. `np-repeat` should be `ng-repeat`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3448besj/